# Show that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{y-1}(-1)^k\frac{\binom{y-1}{k}}{k+x}=\frac{(x-1)!(y-1)!}{(x+y-1)!}$.

Tags: integration, binomial-coefficients, summation, gamma-function

> Prove that for $x,y$ positive integers,
>
> $$\sum_{k=0}^{y-1}(-1)^k\frac{\binom{y-1}{k}}{k+x}=\frac{(x-1)!(y-1)!}{(x+y-1)!}$$

One way is to use the beta-gamma functions relation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function

Is there a direct way to calculate the sum?

Comment: I do not see your formula in the link.

Comment: The formula follows from the beta function by integrating the following between $u=0$ and $u=1$, $$\sum _{k=0}^{y-1}{y-1\choose k} \left( -1 \right) ^{k}{u}^{k+x-1}=
 \left( -u+1 \right) ^{y-1}{u}^{x-1}$$ (No idea how else to get it...)

Comment: Gosper's algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gosper's_algorithm) is an elementary way to evaluate this sum. You can read about it in this (free) book (http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/Downld.html)